# How to remove extrayear from biblatex publist style?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

When using `style=publist` from `biblatex`, book entries are printed following this model.

> **2020b.** *Book Title*. Location: Publisher.

I would like to remove the letters that come with the years (i.e. the `extrayear`) and have that same entry printed as follows:

> **2020.** *Book Title*. Location: Publisher.

I want all entry types to have its `extrayear` removed and that *only its* `date` *is printed*. I said date and not year because I don't want to prevent some entries from being printed as follows:

> **Dec. 6, 2019.** "Article title". In: *Journal* (51), pp. 31–6.

Comment: Please consider adding an example document that reproduces the problem. Your question is of course understandable without it, but it is much easier to get started investigating this if we don't have to build your setup from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the option `labeldateparts=false` or define

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{}
```

Comment: +1 for `labeldateparts=false`. But I consider empty field formats to suppress the output *very* bad style, so I'd like to discourage the second option in the strongest possible terms.

Comment: OK, I retract that ;-)